# Close button event on OS X app swift 2.2

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am creating an OSX app with swift version 2.2. I need to execute a method when the user clicking the close button on top left corner of my app, I am new in Cocoa programming anyone now which is the event executing when clicking close button (see the image).

[image: Close button]

My purpose is when i keep my app on dock it is not open after clicking close button(the black dot under app is showing after clicking close button), but in a case right click and force quit on it then clicking app on dock it will re open fine. I think by giving the below given code inside close button event will solve my problem.

```
NSApplication.sharedApplication().terminate(self)
```

Comment: The close button isn't the close button of the app, it is the close button of the window.

Comment: in my app only have one window that's why i ask for that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
    NSApplication.sharedApplication().terminate(self)
    return true
}
```

Inside appdeligate work for me.

**For Swift 4.2**

```
func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
    NSApplication.shared.terminate(self)
    return true
}
```

Comment: Just return `true`, the application should terminate, as the name of the method says.

Answer (score 9):

Update for Swift 4.1:

```
func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
    NSApplication.shared.terminate(self)
    return true
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `NSApplication.shared.terminate(self)` line.